# mysqli_query() and mysqli_close expects parameter 1 to be mysqli - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

*Repeatedly getting this error, looked through other stackoverflows with the same error but none are similar to my code.*

Here's my loop to get the data from the database.

```
<?php
session_start();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tips";

if($result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql))
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
    printf("%s (%s)\n",$row[0],$row[1]);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

**The errors:**

```
 Error 1:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli(on line 6)
    Error 2:  mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli(on line 15)
```

Here is the connection file I am using

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$user = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "fortunef_db";

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $user, $password, $dbname); //used to connect to the database

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
     die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
?>
```

The error states that it expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, parameter 1 is my connection variable, which as you can see by the above code is in mysqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$mysqli` is not defined anywhere in your first script. It looks like you meant to include the second script at the top of the first one, but you didn't. So do that and your problem will go away.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("WhateverThatOtherScriptIsCalled.php");
...
```

Comment: I literally just spotted it myself haha thanks for the reply! literally spent hours staring at the code

Answer (score 1):

You refer to $mysqli but you never declare it...

Comment: Correct sir, thank you for your input